# What happens to the graph of a function, whose limit is of the form $1^{\infty}$?

Tags: limits

Is the function just undefined or it has the value of the limit? I am just unable to understand which case it is
..

Comment: It is an undefined form

Comment: Can you justify it?

Comment: $(1 + 1/n)^n\to e$ while $1^n\to 1$

Comment: None of the above. If $f(x)=a(x)^{b^(x)}$ for $x>0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}a(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}b(x)=\infty$, then this makes no use at all of $f(0)$, which may be defined or undefined, and if defined need not be equal to said limit

Comment: My question is , take (1+1/n)^n =f(n).Will f(n) be defined or continuous at infinity?

Comment: @AdityaSharma I already answered you

Comment: @AdityaSharma If you define $f(n)$ like that, then *presumably* you implicitly assume $n\in\Bbb N$. As $\infty\notin\Bbb N$, this makes $f$ not defined at $\infty$. Nevertheless $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ exists.

Comment: Suppose n is any real number?

Comment: @AdityaSharma $\infty\notin\Bbb R$ either

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen please see my answer and let me know if I'm right.

Comment: Please, search the site. All the variations of this question have been asked and answered multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

To get clarity on why $ 1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form , see this example ,

Let a function $$ f : R^{+} \to R $$
$$ f(x) = x^{n}$$
And $g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty } f(x)$

g(x) at different locations of x will be :
For $ x \subseteq [0,1) , g(x) = 0$
For $ x \subseteq (1,\infty) , g(x) \to \infty$
For $ x = 1 , g(x) = 1$

We can see that in the neighborhood of 1 , i.e $ {1 - \delta , 1 + \delta } $ , the function has different values , which makes it impossible to assign a value for $g(x) at x \to 1 $

For this reason , it is not possible to assign a value for $1^{\infty}$
Hence , $1^{\infty}$ is an indeterminate form.

Comment: I think there's a typo after 'And $g(x) =$ ...' :)

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- "Infinity" is not a number; it is rather a mathematical symbol. Saying things like $f(\infty)$ makes as much sense as saying $f(\text{Albert Einstein})$, i.e. no sense at all.
- The value of the limit as $x\to \infty$ will tell what will be the approximate value if the function when you input really, *really* large numbers.

P.S. I'm a student myself so a request to fellow users to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: See [this answer by Paramanand Singh](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1897929/721644).

Comment: @Cheesecake I read the answer but I'm unable to say for sure if I'm right or wrong.

Comment: You're correct , but [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1576282/72164)  is a concise answer, also by Paramanand Singh, one should definitely read.

Comment: @Cheesecake Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome!